# How to revert to MonoDevelop's old "ctrl-tab" behavior?

Tags: unity, productivity, monodevelop

I believe MonoDevelop (bundled with Unity3D) has changed its `ctrl-tab` and `ctrl-shift-tab` behavior and I would like to get back to the old behavior, as the new way frustrates my workflow.

`Ctrl-tab` (and `ctrl-shift-tab`) previously (and ought to) go to the "last viewed tab", in a similar way to how `alt-tab` works on Windows. Unfortunately there seems to have been a change and now it goes to the "tab on the left of the current one".

An example of why this is frustrating: quickly looking at a class definition, you hit `F12` to load the definition (perhaps in a new tab), and then you want to go back to the code you were working on. Previously you could hit `ctrl-tab` and you'd be back there. Now you can't do that and you have to actually remember what you were doing, which isn't good for my workflow (read: ailing memory).

I'm not sure when the change happened, or if it's a setting somewhere (I can't find it). I'm running Unity 5.1.2p2 and its bundled MonoDev 4.0.1. Noticed it after a clean install of Windows 10.

How can I fix this to revert to the old behaviour, or is there some other method to jump back to the last viewed tab?

It seems pedantic but it has a major impact on my productivity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use or configure MonoDevelop.

Comment: It's about MonoDevelop as configured, bundled and installed by Unity3D. There are many Unity questions in this forum, but you can move it to another stack exchange site if you want. It's already answered anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/613355/document-switcher-is-gone-monodevelop.html

Edit C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \AppData\Roaming\MonoDevelop-Unity-4.0\Config\MonoDevelopProperties.xml

Set the `MonoDevelop.Core.Gui.EnableDocumentSwitchDialog` property to `True`

Comment: Thank you! That edit to %APPDATA%\MonoDevelop-Unity-4.0\Config\MonoDevelopProperties.xml did the trick.